# ST_Covers(envelope, point) yields different results for same point

Tags: postgis, geography-data-type

Clearly missing a basic concept. Using ST_Covers, I'm getting "true" for a geography point that clearly exists outside of the polygon. Looking at a number of points, it appears latitudes are vertically shifted, whereby points a bit North of the polygon are considered "in" and points just above the Southern border are erroneously considered "out".

For example, a single point in the database is defined as `geography(Point,4326)`, with latitude longitude (45º, -79º).

Using ST_MakeEnvelope, create a polygon ranging N/S 40 to 42º, and E/W from -102º to -50º. The point "should" be just north of the resulting polygon.

However `ST_Covers(ST_MakeEnvelope(-102, 40, -50, 42, 4326), location)` returns true.

Yet `ST_Covers(ST_MakeEnvelope(-102, 40, -50, 42, 4326), ST_Point(-79, 45, 4326))` returns false as expected.

You can see this in the following... shouldn't the location cast as geography(Point,4326) result in the same answer as the non-cast ST_Point?

(I'm storing global aviation positions & store locations as geography data types rather than geometry.)

```
    select 
      PostGIS_Version(),
      ST_Covers(ST_MakeEnvelope(-102, 40, -50, 42, 4326), ST_Point(-79, 45, 4326)) as AsPoint,
      ST_Covers(ST_MakeEnvelope(-102, 40, -50, 42, 4326), ST_Point(-79, 45)::geography(Point,4326)) as AsPointGeo
```

Results in:

| version | aspoint | aspointgeo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3.2<...> | false | true |

Comment: Great ellipse routes.

Comment: That seems so obvious, gonna check that!

Answer (score 1):

Not surprising, @Vince provided the useful prompt.

`ST_Covers(a, b)` works with geometry and with geography types. Both a & b must be (i.e., will be converted to be) the same type.

Geometry types would yield (my) expected results: If the envelope has a northern edge of 42º, then any point north of 42º would be "outside" the envelope.

Geography types are treated differently, though the envelope *appears* to be the same (i.e., *maxy* or max Latitude is 42º), the upper bound of the envelope is the great-circle curve between the two lat/lon points (42º, -102º) and (42º, -50º). The curve extends north of the 42º between the two endpoints and happens to cover my point (45º, -79º).

I didn't type the ST_Envelope (which is really just a Polygon). But, automatic type conversion causes:

```
ST_Cover(Polygon, point:geometry) => geometry calculation
   -but-  
ST_Cover(Polygon, point:geography) => geography calculation
```

So, one way to *force* the intended calculation, especially if the type of point is not know (or varies) is to explicitly cast:

```
ST_Cover(ST_MakeEnvelope(-102, 40, -50, 42, 4326), location::geometry)
   -or-
ST_Cover(ST_MakeEnvelope(-102, 40, -50, 42, 4326), location::geography)
```

With the *location* set to your preferred type, the Polygon is coerced to geometry or geography and the resulting ST_Covers uses the appropriate bounds.